# Invert svg polyline

Tags: css, svg, polyline, viewbox

I tried several times but i cant find the points to invert this < to >

```html
<p style="text-align: right;">
  <svg 
    class="uk-visible@m" 
    width="50" 
    height="100" 
    viewbox="5 5 13 13" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  >
    <polyline 
      fill="none" 
      stroke="#ff6633" 
      stroke-width="1.6" 
      points="25,1 5.3,10 25,19"
    ></polyline>
  </svg>
</p>
```

Any knows? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just `transform` thing :)

```html
<p style="text-align: right;">
  <svg 
    class="uk-visible@m" 
    style="transform: rotate(180deg);" 
    width="50" 
    height="100" 
    viewbox="5 5 13 13" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  >
    <polyline 
      fill="none" 
      stroke="#ff6633" 
      stroke-width="1.6" 
      points="25,1 5.3,10 25,19"
    ></polyline>
  </svg>
</p>
```

Comment: Why if i use both together aren't and the same height?

Answer (score 0):

Just change 180d to scaleX(-1).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Given the viewBox that you are using, the equivalent horizontally-flipped coordinates for your polyline are:

```
-2,1 17.7,10 -2,19
```

Explanation:

- Horizontally, your viewBox spans from x = 5 to x = 18 (5+13).
- To flip horizontally you have to flip the X coordinates from one side of your viewBox to the other.
- The first and last X coords are 25. That is 7 past the right edge of the viewBox (18). So to flip that, we need to subtract 7 from the *left edge* of the viewBox. That makes those -2.
- The middle X coord is 5.3. That is 0.3 inside the left edge of the viewBox (5). So the flipped version needs to be 0.3 inside the *right edge*. So 18 - 0.3 becomes 17.7.

So `25,1 5.3,10 25,19` becomes `-2,1 17.7,10 -2,19`.

```html
<p style="text-align: right;"><svg class="uk-visible@m" width="50" height="100" viewbox="5 5 13 13" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polyline fill="none" stroke="#ff6633" stroke-width="1.6" points="-2,1 17.7,10 -2,19"></polyline></svg></p>
```